# Is the ASP.NET Ajax Library dead?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I've recently stumbled across a few blogs that say the ASP.NET Ajax Library is dead, in particular:

- http://encosia.com/2010/10/04/understanding-jquerys-impact-on-microsoft-and-asp-net/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/toddanglin/archive/2010/04/19/microsoft-ajax-client-library-is-dead-long-live-jquery.aspx

Is this generally true, technically and practically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Even for SharePoint developers (which uses ASP.net AJAX heavily) it's out of favor.

However, the SERVER SIDE ASP.net AJAX (UpdatePanel etc.) are alive and kicking. They have some shortcomings (UpdatePanel can send tons of viewstate back and forth).

But the Client Side Framework and ASP.net AJAX Library is dead.

Answer (score 4):

I've been to Microsoft talks on jQuery, and basically it sounded to me like they expected everyone to use jQuery for client-side-only DOM manipulation and ASP.NET Ajax was still used for it's Ajax components (like UpdatePanel) and as a basis for AJAX into .NET services made with WCF or just back to ASHX or other server code.

From being a component developer that targets ASP.NET, I can tell you that it's very much used by our customers, and we need to support it.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the different between ASP.NET AJAX (alive and well) and the ASP.NET Ajax Library (dead).

Answer (score 2):

Scalable comet ajax is more popular now. Try the samples of **[PokeIn](http://pokein.codeplex.com)** library.

Answer (score 0):

A technology can't die if it's customer base is so big!

Comment: @AlexanderN I think what Lorenzo means is that developers will not use it for new development. However, developers maintaining older code-bases may continue to use it. For example, some developers still get paid to maintain cobol.