# ASP.NET UpdatePanel does not work in IE7

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer-7, updatepanel

This is a puzzling problem because I can't seem to find any information on it on the net - normally a thousand others have suffered before me! The problem is that, for me, UpdatePanel flat out doesn't work in IE7. This is consistent across various websites I've created. Every time I invoke the partial page update, I get a server error, but so far I've been unable to determine anything more about that error. When I submit the page in debug mode, I somehow get redirected to the site default page. When running without custom errors on, I get this uninformative javascript error:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; GTB7.4; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Timestamp: Fri, 16 Nov 2012 05:54:40 UTC

Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500
Line: 885
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://www.[mydomain.com]/ScriptResource.axd?d=vjlljng03Lto1XsXmrAVz7i5C6Bt1evgQVQf-nNIyurN26GPnFkncgLCr7PGaj8sfKs6grEbG_O-qcEl76OIJ_BoaGp2R3yAZtdR1hkN-YfJloSbcJEvLPYAOdW64lGkYd_FpaSv1gEYdL_Czn4SJB8QsIbh7VhSobiYXc0Sb7s88HriVvuninBJpV-vR6ML0&t=6119e399

I even stepped through MS's javascript once to try to nail this down, but never succeeded. I'm very happy to post some code if that will help. It seems amazing that no-one else is reporting this problem given its consistency.

Comment: I suppose there is a real server error, here. Try debbugging with Visual Studio and see if it stops somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with CDN in ScriptManager?

Below links may be helpful

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2009/11/23/asp-net-4-0-scriptmanager-improvements.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/announcing-the-microsoft-ajax-cdn.aspx

Also [Is the ASP.NET Ajax Library dead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250637/is-the-asp-net-ajax-library-dead)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. As for ASP.NET AJAX's death, well we're slowly transitioning to MVC, but there's a ton of legacy code to convert, and besides, that article says UpdatePanel still lives. Sure it's bloated, but it's still great for RAD.

Comment: Nope, didn't help :( For the time being I'm conditionally disabling partial page update for IE7, and this 'fixes' it - at an obvious cost. But I have a further clue in the fact that I get redirected back to the home page when I submit- it's as if the page is not posting back to itself properly but posting back to the site root.